# How to run Three20 Unit Tests?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, three20

Anyone have idea how to run Three20's Unit Tests?

I have downloaded their package from github but really have no idea on how to run the unit tests?

Comment: Removed the `facebook` tag... I don't see a question relevant to facebook development here.

Comment: right click delete - check out http://nimbuskit.info/ instead. Walk throughs and heavy documentation. Designed by Jeff the latest Three20 coordinator.

Comment: to add to rocky's comment, as i understand it three20 is not going to be developed anymore so unless you really need to be using three20 you should think about switching to nimbus.

Comment: So you mean Three20 is dead now?

Comment: Maybe not dead.  It's open source so people may continue to develop for it.  It's still ok to use  but I wouldn't bet on it keeping up with iOS changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Three20 workspace has a scheme to easily let you run all UnitTests across all Three20 subprojects.

It's not that many test right now, but we hope the number will grow in the future.